# angularJS how to change attrs in directive's link

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I set a progress in my app
I want to controll The progress in angular's directive
but how can I change `data-value` and `data-total` in directive's link func?

**app.html**

```
    <div class="ui indicating small progress" data-value="39" data-total="50" plan-progress>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="progress"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In this html, I want change `data-value` and `data-total`

I try this:

**app.js**

```
  todoApp.directive('planProgress', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        attrs.value = 10
        attrs.total = 20
        elem.progress();
      }
    };
  });
```

But it doesn't work
so I want to know how to change it in my directive?

Comment: why you not set this attributes directly in html?

Comment: what？ this attributes already in html, i just want to change it when data change

Comment: Another thing that caught my attention, `elem.progress()`? What is that or you just trying something?

Comment: @nataila, in html you have `data-value="39" data-total="50"` why not `data-value="10" data-total="20"`?

Comment: @Grundy I just want to change them in JS....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `attrs.$set()` in your link function and recompile the element. Also, don't forget to inject the `$compile` service to your directive. 
In your html you've added the directive as an attribute but didn't mention it in the restrict value in your directive definition. You need to mention it in directive definition.
See the code bellow:

```
todoApp.directive('planProgress', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        attrs.$set('value', 10);
        attrs.$set('total', 20);
        $compile(elem)(scope);
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Correct answer, but I have one question should this not be done automatically? I have tried `$scope.$apply` with the original code and it says $apply is already in progress. So it would be logical that the DOM is updated but why do you need to recompile?

Comment: @ Mikey : did you try scope.$digest()? instead of $scope?

Comment: Yes sorry I did it without the dollar sign `scope.$apply()`. But that gave me back the error that `$apply()` was already in progress. I have not tried triggering the digest cycle manually.

Comment: @Md.MahbubulHaque  and how can I get `value` and `total`? there is `value` in `attrs` but I can get it with `attrs.value`  ?

Comment: @ nataila : you can use attrs.value and attrs.total for getting the attribute values in link function. syntax will be attrs.attributeName

Comment: @Md.MahbubulHaque I can't get attributeName with `attrs.attributeName` , I get data with `$http` and I get `value` in directive,  but I cant's get value, is it the reason of `$http`?

Comment: @ nataila : can you please show me the code? Assuming that  you want to get data from $http service within directive. Did you forget to inject $http service in your directive? By the way it would be better if you use factory/service to get the data and inject that factory/service in your directive to access them. Or use that factory/service in your controller to get data. and you can get that controller data through scope in directive. Because of this architectural change is directives are supposed to deal DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
 attrs["data-value"] = 10;
 attrs["data-total"] = 20;
```

You don't want to use  `attrs.data-total = 20` because the `-` will force a subtraction.

It's always legal in javascript to use `x[keyName]` instead of `x.keyName`, and you must use this second notation when keyName is a strange key such as `**$^ùjsls*` or `data-value`. A more useful case is when the key is a variable.

On last thing : as you do, you will always rewrite the coder's inputs. It may have sense, but it's not very elegant.

Comment: I try this, it doesn't work, this is no "data-value" in attrs'keys, there is `value` and `total` in attrs, I try to  set `attrs["value"] = 10` and `attrs["value"]=10`  and they all don't work

Comment: put a alert("here") or a debugger break point to be sure you are there. The benefit of the breakpoint is to be sure of the data inside attrs. If value change, it's because it is also changed elsewhere.